# Is there any chance to pass query params as like ?id="idValue" in route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router v4. We can pass query params in v4 as /user/:id?. But, I need to pass query params in route like /user/?id="id".

Any help or suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: Do you want the path to be like /user?id="id" or pass query param with Link component

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `search` property on location object which react router passes to all components

E.g. if your route is `/user?id=1`, then

```
console.log(this.props.location.search) // ?id=1
```

You can then use a library like [`query-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to parse those query params

```
import queryString from 'query-string'

// inside your component
const params = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
params.id === 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using context as follows,

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
class Sample extends React.Component {
  static get contextTypes() {
    return {
      router: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };
  }
.....
 handleSubmit(data) {
    let query = {}
    query['id'] = data.id
    this.context.router.push({
      pathname:'/path',
      query: query
    });
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HOC which will extract and parse `search` property of `location` object provided by React Router to underlying component. Like this:

```
const withQuery = Component => props => {
  if (props.location && props.location.search) {
    const query = props.location.search.substr(1)
      .split('&')
      .reduce((carry, pair) => {
        const [ key, val ] = pair.split('=');
        carry[unescape(key)] = unescape(val);
        return carry;
      }, {});
    return <Component {...props} query={query} />
  } else {
    return <Component {...props} query={{}} />
  }
}
```

and wrap components rendered by according `<Route />`:

```
<Route
  path="/query"
  component={withQuery(MyComponent)}
/>
```

Take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/546rq707q4) to get the idea in details.